# use of patterns symbol in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am new to regex,

Can anyone explain for me the patterns:

```
[a-fA-F\d]{30}

[\d\w]

[-+_~.\d\w]

[-\d\w]{0,253}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, few notes:

1. `\d` is the shorthand to express any digit. `[0-9]` and character class `[[:digit:]]` are analogous to `\d`.
2. `\w` is the shorthand for all alphanumerics and `_`. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `[[:alnum:]_]` are analogous to `\w`.

Now the Regex patterns:

- `[a-fA-F\d]{30}` will match any of the characters among `abcdefABCDEF0123456789` exactly 30 times.
- `[\d\w]` will match any single character between `[0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Note that `\w` contains `[0-9]` so you don't need `\d`. Just use `\w`.
- `[-+_~.\d\w]` will match any single character between `-+_~.[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Note that `\w` alreadly contains `_` and `[0-9]` so you don't need to explicitely mention `_` and `\d`. This can be simplified as `[-+~.\w]`
- `[-\d\w]{0,253}` will match any of the characters between `-`, `[0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with a minimum of 0 to a maximum of 253 times. Again `\d` is not needed, you can use `[-\w]{0,253}`